# Create Timesheet using PSI Project Server 2013 - General Invalid Operation

Tags: c#, ms-project-server-2013, psi

I'm trying to use the TimeSheet.CreateTimesheet method from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg239017.aspx) but unfortunately I receive the General Invalid Operation error from my console.

I suspect it's a permissions problem, because of I have followed all of the instructions posted in the entrance from msdn linked before.

Here are the MAIN code:

```
// Here are the variables
SvcTimeSheet.TimesheetDataSet timesheetDs;
SvcTimeSheet.TimeSheet timeSheetSvc = new SvcTimeSheet.TimeSheet();
timeSheetSvc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
timeSheetSvc.Url = PROJECT_SERVER_URI + TIMESHEET_SERVICE_PATH;
Guid myUid = resourceSvc.GetCurrentUserUid();
SvcAdmin.TimePeriodDataSet timeperiodDs =   adminSvc.ReadPeriods(SvcAdmin.PeriodState.Open);
Guid periodUid = timeperiodDs.TimePeriods[0].WPRD_UID;

// Here are the Timesheet creation method
timesheetDs = new SvcTimeSheet.TimesheetDataSet();
SvcTimeSheet.TimesheetDataSet.HeadersRow headersRow = timesheetDs.Headers.NewHeadersRow();
headersRow.RES_UID = myUid;
headersRow.TS_UID = Guid.NewGuid();
headersRow.WPRD_UID = periodUid;
headersRow.TS_CREATOR_RES_UID = myUid;
headersRow.TS_NAME = "Timesheet ";
headersRow.TS_COMMENTS = "Random comment text here";
headersRow.TS_ENTRY_MODE_ENUM = (byte)PSLibrary.TimesheetEnum.EntryMode.Weekly;
timesheetDs.Headers.AddHeadersRow(headersRow);

// Create the timesheet with the default line types that are specified by the admin.
timeSheetSvc.CreateTimesheet(timesheetDs, SvcTimeSheet.PreloadType.Assignments);
timesheetDs = timeSheetSvc.ReadTimesheet(headersRow.TS_UID);
```

When `timeSheetSvc.CreateTimesheet(timesheetDs, SvcTimeSheet.PreloadType.Assignments);` it is called, I get the General Invalid Operation.

Anybody knows what that means? Or where can I find further information about?

**EDIT:**

Here are the screenshot from my PSI Console, that parses the error:

[image: PSIConsole error]

Thanks in advance,